# Showing that $g(X)$ is a random variable and comparing $\sigma (X)$ and $\sigma (g(X)) $

Tags: probability, measure-theory, random-variables

Let $(\Omega, F, P)$ be a probability space and $X:(\Omega,F)\to (\mathbb{R},B_{\mathbb{R}})$ be a random variable. If $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R} $ is continuous then $Y:=g(X)$ is a random variable.

To prove it, it suffices to show that for all open $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, $Y^{-1}(A)=X^{-1}(g^{-1}(A))\in F.$ Since $g$ is continuous, $g^{-1}(A) $ is open and thus the claim follows from $X$ being a random variable. Am I right?

What relationship do $\sigma(X)$ and $\sigma(g(X))$ have? I think $\sigma(X)=X^{-1}(\mathbb{R}) $ and $\sigma(g(X))=Y^{-1}(\mathbb{R})=X^{-1}(g^{-1}(\mathbb{R})),$ whence $\sigma (g (X))\subseteq\sigma(X)$.

Comment: Note that $X^{-1}(\mathbb{R})=\Omega$, so what you wrote at the end is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer to the first part looks pretty much perfect to me. You should be careful with notation with the second part ($\sigma (X)\neq X^{-1}(\mathbb R)$) but the idea and conclusion are both right. If I were to add anything, I would say that we do not have $\sigma (Y)=\sigma (X)$ in general (take $g$ constant, for instance) but equality is possible, say if $g$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: Thank you, indeed I see that I misread some notes, and $X^{-1}(\mathbb{R})=\Omega $. According to those notes, $\sigma(X)=X^{-1}(B_{\mathbb{R}}) $ should make sense, does it?

Comment: It makes sense, but I personally do not like the notation and would instead write $\sigma (X)=\{X^{-1}(A):A\in B_{\mathbb R}\}$.